# Is it possible to expand variables in jPath when setting a property in bot composer?

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to set a property in Bot composer using jPath and 2 user variables I've set further up stream... The first user variable 'user.allRpiClients' is an array of objects, for example like this:

```
[
 {"name":"tenant1","id":"abc"},
 {"name":"tenant2","id":"def"}
]
```

The second user variable 'user.selectedClientName' is set to a string 'tenant1' we'll say

now I want to set a new property 'user.selectedClientId' using the setProperty tool and jPath adaptive expression... I've tried various combinations but can't get it to work:

```
=jPath(user.allRpiClients, "$[?(@.name=='user.selectedClientName')].id")
=jPath(user.allRpiClients, "$[?(@.name=='${user.selectedClientName}')].id")
=jPath(`${user.allRpiClients}`, "$[?(@.name=='user.selectedClientName')].id")
```

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong, or if this is even possible with Bot composer setProperty tool?

Answer (score 1):

With Adaptive Expressions we followed pattern of Javascript...which is to use the back-tick character to mean string interpolation. https://betterprogramming.pub/javascript-how-backticks-work-de269e0fb8ba

```
var world = "Earth";
"Hello ${world}" => "Hello ${world}"  // double quote
'Hello ${world}" => "Hello ${world}'  // single quote
`Hello ${world}` => "Hello Earth"     // backtick quote
```

This makes it relatively easy to work with strings and expressions together.

When you start with "=..." you are saying "interpret all of this as expressions and then you are creating a string as an argument to jPath. Just use back-tick and all should be good.

```
jPath(user.allRpiClients, `$[?(@.name=="${user.selectedClientName}")].id`)
```